# Why redis cluster requires at least 3 master nodes

Tags: redis

The cluster spec(http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) does not give a reason for this requirement. I guess it is because both the failure detection and the failover process require the majority of master nodes to reach an agreement. If we have only 2 masters and one failed, the other master node cannot make up the decision according to the protocol. Is this correct?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/q/815764/412043

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have pointed out is right. 
It is suggested to have three master node and one slave to each of them.

http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial: 
Note that the minimal cluster that works as expected requires to contain at least three master nodes. For your first tests it is strongly suggested to start a six nodes cluster with three masters and three slaves.

---

Still you might be able to create cluster with less than three master node but that will affect the failover process you already pointed.